# Selecting multiple sql tables giving a value "?"

Tags: sql, node.js, express

I have the next code:

```
bd.query('SELECT Foto.*, Video.* FROM Foto, Video WHERE Foto.id_usuario = Video.id_usuario AND Video.id_usuario=1', function(error,filas)
```

But after the "AND" statement instead of giving a specific value I'd like to add a dynamic one like I do in a normal sql select:

```
bd.query('UPDATE Oferta SET ?,? WHERE ?', [{titulo:titulo},{descripcion:descripcion},{id:id}], function(error,filas)
```

What I've tried to do was this:

```
bd.query('SELECT Foto.*, Video.* FROM Foto, Video WHERE Foto.id_usuario = Video.id_usuario AND ?',{id_usuario:id}, function(error,filas)
```

But it's not working! I can't find any place where someone has done anything similar :( maybe because I don't know how to search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use named placeholder you have to pass a single object, like this:

```
bd.query('SELECT Foto.*, Video.* FROM Foto, Video WHERE Foto.id_usuario = Video.id_usuario AND id = :id',{id: id}, function(error,filas)

bd.query('UPDATE Oferta SET titulo = :titulo, descripcion = :descripcion WHERE id = :id', {titulo:titulo,descripcion:descripcion, id:id}, function(error,filas)
```

otherwise you can use simple placeholders like suggested by Oscar :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you passed an object in you second sentence and an array of objects in your third sentence.

Can you try to pass only the array with the values and without key.
The substitution multiple would be like this:

**case 2:** `bd.query('SELECT Foto.*, Video.* FROM Foto, Video WHERE Foto.id_usuario = Video.id_usuario AND ?',[id], function(error,filas)`

**case 3:** `bd.query('UPDATE Oferta SET ?,? WHERE ?', [titulo,descripcion,id], function(error,filas)`

Comment: Hi Oscar! Thank you for your help, I finally fixed it like this: 
    bd.query('SELECT Foto.*, Video.* FROM Foto, Video WHERE Foto.id_usuario = Video.id_usuario AND Video.?',{id_usuario:id}, function(error,filas)